# Перебор записей по определенным параметрам

Tags: php, sql, выборка

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать выборку записей по определенным параметрам. Например в БД есть таблица users со следующими полями.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как из данной таблицы достать все записи где user или place равно 2 после этого пройти по цепочке 4,5,6 т.к. первая цифра встретилась на id=4 дальше происходит уже поиск 4, а id4 встречается на id=5 и так до конца. Из данного примера ожидается получить на выходе следующие записи

id - 4,5,6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слабовменяемое условие. Но если пытаться выполнить его в точности, получится

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users u, (SELECT id
               FROM users
               WHERE 2 IN (user, place)
              ) x
WHERE (u.id > x.id AND u.user = x.id)
   OR u.id = x.id
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```